# Material on Koszul complex

Tags: reference-request

I have tried a lot of books to understand Koszul complex but eventually failed. I have tried Eisenbud's book, Weibel's homological algebra, but I just can not how to construct Koszul complex by tensor product and why this is equivalent to the construction by exterior algebra. Could some one recommend some more clearer treatment on Koszul complex? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about them?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Dear Mariano, basically, I want to know the  different definitions of Koszul complex and the proof of their equivalences. Koszul resolution, and duality.

Comment: You could read the book by Alexander Polishchuk, ‎Leonid Positselski  called *Quadratic Algebras*.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks! I will read it !